# How to place a sap.m.Button in sap.m.Toolbar on the right?

Tags: sapui5

I create a toolbar from sap.m with this code:

```js
var oPage = new sap.m.Page({
    title: "Statusverfolgung",
    footer: new sap.m.Toolbar({
        content: [
            new sap.m.Button({
                text: "Next status"
            })
        ]
    }),
    content: [
        oBox
    ]
});
```

Now this button is placed to the left. How can I place it to the right?

Answer (score 6):

Use [ToolbarSpacer](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ToolbarSpacer.html) before Button, which is used for horizontal spacing between toolbar items.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/jonige/1/edit?html,js,output) is working example.

Answer (score 3):

And If you were doing in xml, use this code

```html
<footer>
  <Bar>
    <contentRight>
      <Button
        text="Next status"
        press="onPressButton" />
    </contentRight>
  </Bar>
</footer>
```

Comment: which namespace to include for contentRight ?